# Nginx Print log for last 10min where nginx has time Stamp Format "time_iso8601"

Tags: shell-script, awk, nginx

Purpose: To print last 10min nginx api_access.log from current time in the server.

**How I tried:**

I tried to compare the timestamp in nginx api_access.log with current time and then print the logs which are for past 10min.

**Command Used:**

```
awk -F'["+]' -v d1="$(date --date '-10 min' '+%FT%T')" -v d2="$(date '+%FT%T')" '
  $4 > d1 && $4 <d2 || $4 ~ d2' api_access.log
```

**Nginx api_access.log:**

```
{"@timestamp":"2020-06-15T12:36:38+00:00","msec":1592224598.704,"remote_addr":xxx xxxx}
{"@timestamp":"2020-06-15T12:51:41+00:00","msec":1592225501.530,"remote_addr":xxx xxxx}
```

**Failure:**

Unable to compare current time and with 2020-06-15T12:36:38+00:00 format and print the last 10min logs from the api_access.log

Please help...

Comment: [edit] your question to include the output of `awk --version` and add concise, testable sample input and expected output that demonstrates your requirements and that we could test a potential solution with. Is `--date '-1 min'` a typo and you meant to write `--date '-10 min'`?

Comment: I have edited the question and provided more info.

Answer (score 0):

Using GNU `awk` and converting the dates to timestamps:

```
awk -v d1="$(date -d '-10 min' '+%s')" -v d2="$(date '+%s')" -F'[-":,T+]' '
  { ts=mktime($5" "$6" "$7" "$8" "$9" "$10) }
  ts >= d1 && ts <= d2
  ts > d2{ exit 0 }
' api_access.log
```

The last line immediately exits the script if the encountered timestamp is greater than the timestamp of the current date.